# using javacamera2view in opencv

Tags: android, opencv, face-detection, android-camera2

I am very new to both java and opencv especially android. From reading, I know that camera2 API support higher resolution compared to camera1 API, which is useful for my project.
I am trying to understand face-detection sample from open cv. I know that there are javacameraview and javacamera2view classes.
so far, I understand that the activity using javacameraview. however, I don't know where the javacameraview initially called. no decalaration at all.

I believe it is called in camerabridgeviewbase. but I cannot find any initialization of javacameraview.

The main goal is to replace javacameraview with javacamera2view. or use camera2 API directly.
I understand that there are some limitation in camera2 API but that is not the main problem now.

Here is the CameraBridgeViewBase initialisation

```java
    private static final String TAG = "CameraBridge";
    protected static final int MAX_UNSPECIFIED = -1;
    private static final int STOPPED = 0;
    private static final int STARTED = 1;

    private int mState = STOPPED;
    private Bitmap mCacheBitmap;
    private CvCameraViewListener2 mListener;
    private boolean mSurfaceExist;
    private final Object mSyncObject = new Object();

    protected int mFrameWidth;
    protected int mFrameHeight;
    protected int mMaxHeight;
    protected int mMaxWidth;
    protected float mScale = 1;
    protected int mPreviewFormat = RGBA;
    protected int mCameraIndex = CAMERA_ID_ANY;
    protected boolean mEnabled;
    protected boolean mCameraPermissionGranted = false;
    protected FpsMeter mFpsMeter = null;

    public static final int CAMERA_ID_ANY   = -1;
    public static final int CAMERA_ID_BACK  = 99;
    public static final int CAMERA_ID_FRONT = 98;
    public static final int RGBA = 1;
    public static final int GRAY = 2;
```

cheers

Answer (score 0):

Well iam looking in the wrong place. It is controlled in the layout. Just replace JavaCameraView with JavaCamera2View. And done. Camera2 implemented.

Comment: just a question on a partially related topic, did you manage to get the `camera2view` work in portrait mode?